# Android: How to stop Android 1.6+ from scaling images

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, drawable

I updated my build to build against Android 1.6, and now my bitmaps are scaled down on high density screens. I do NOT want this behavior. I gave this a shot:

http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/190539066/android-unscaled-bitmaps

but the images are STILL scaling, that is UNLESS I set them to a specific height & width. If I use `wrap_content` they are scaled down.

I have an image loader using the unscaled bitmap loader to create a drawable like so:

```
Bitmap bm = UnscaledBitmapLoader.loadFromResource(imageBufferInputStream);
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
```

which I later assign to an ImageView like so:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable( copyBitmapDrawable( (BitmapDrawable) drawable) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the bitmap with a `Drawable` is the problem. The `Drawable` scales the `Bitmap`. Instead of using a `Drawable`, assign the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` directly using `imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have an image not scaled when loading it from a resource (e.g. with BitmapFactory.decodeResource) you have to locate it in res/drawable-nodpi instead of the usual drawable, drawable-ldpi and so on.

Comment: I'm downloading these from the web.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), bmp);
```

instead of

```
 new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
```

should solve the issue.

Comment: I have just spent a while trying to solve this exact same problem, and this was all it took to solve it. Upvoted, since this is a more useful generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). The `CENTER` constant preforms no scaling, so I guess that's what you are looking for.

By the way, do you use pixels or dips as size units? Using dips (density-independent-pixels) is a means of standardizing display on multiple resolutions. You'll find a couple of tips [here](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/casting-wide-net-android-devices.html).

Comment: I tried that already, and it doesn't work. Something is scaling it before I assign it to the ImageView.

Comment: Any chance of providing some relevant code snippets (xml,java or whatnot)?